# Handling warning about DX and DY in gdal_translate from .Gtiff to .ASC?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdal-translate, ascii

When I try to convert Gtiff to .asc file, QGIS shows the warning:

```
Producing Golden Surfer style file with DX and DY instead
of CELL SIZE since the input pixels are non-square. Use the
FORCE CELL SIZE = TRUE creation option to force use of DX for
even though this will be distorted. Most ASCII Grid reader
(ArcGIS included) do not support the DX and DY parameters
```

Can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add gdalinfo report about your tiff into your question.

Comment: also add why this is a problem for you, as dx,dy ASCII (non-square cells)  will show just fine in QGIS